# Show that $g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \ dt$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, continuity

> Let $f: \Bbb R \to [0, \infty]$ be integrable. That is $\int_\Bbb R |f| < \infty$. Show that $g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \ dt$ is continuous.

Should this be done with $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ approach? If I consider $$|g(x) - g(y)|= \left| \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \ dt - \int_{-\infty} ^y f(t) \ dt \right| \le \left|\int_{y}^x f(t) \ dt \right|$$ but how should I bound this integral? Is there something I can do with the fact that $f$ is integrable?

Comment: try a proof by contradiction, that is, suppose its not continuous and show a contradiction with the fact of $f$ being integrable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$|g(x+h) - g(x)| \leq \left| \int_x^{x+h}f(t) dt \right| = \left| \int 1_{[x,x+h]}(t) f(t) dt \right|$$

As $h \to 0$, we have that $1_{[x,x+h]}(t) f(t)$ converges pointwise to $1_{\{x\}}(t) f(t)$. By the dominated convergence theorem we get:
$$\left| \int 1_{[x,x+h]}(t) f(t) dt \right| \to \int 1_{\{x\}} f(t) dt = 0 \qquad \text{ as } h \to 0$$

Showing that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: Why is $\int 1_{\{x\}} f(t) dt = 0$?

Comment: @LocomotRagsar $1_{\{x\}}f$ is almost everywhere equal to zero with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: What is the formulation of $1_{\{x\}}f$? I suppose that it's something like $$\begin{cases} f, x \in A \\ 0, x \notin A \end{cases}$$ but not sure what the set $A$ should be.

Comment: @LocomotRagsar if $g(t) = 1_{\{x\}}(t) f(t)$, then when $t=x$, we have $g(x) = f(x)$; otherwise, $g$ is zero.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!